# What does it mean when you get "too many open files" on the Kafka Consumer/Client?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api

I know that this usually means the ulimit needs to be increased. But what does this actually mean when it happens on the consumer side?

I'm using Apache Flink and I got this error on my Flink task node. When I reboot my Flink node and redeployed the job it worked fine. The brokers also seemed fine at the time.

I have a total of 9 tasks running over 3 nodes. Max parallelism for any one job is 1 to 2. So lets assume worst case 18 parallelism/threads over 3 nodes.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:799)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:650)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:630)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaPartitionDiscoverer.initializeConnections(KafkaPartitionDiscoverer.java:58)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractPartitionDiscoverer.open(AbstractPartitionDiscoverer.java:94)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.open(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:504)
at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:102)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openAllOperators(StreamTask.java:424)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:290)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:154)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:188)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:192)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:722)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.makePipe(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:65)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:36)
at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:152)
... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Kafka client (producer, consumer) maintains a single socket per every broker in the cluster its connected to (worst case).

so youre looking at number of clients flink creates times number of brokers in your cluster

sockets count as handles for purposes of ulimit.

I dont know how many kafka clients flink creates internally - you could grab a heap dump and see how many client objects are in there

Comment: I believe it's one client instance per the "parallelism" setting. So if I set it to 2 then 2 clients will get created. So the maximum I should have open over the 3 nodes should be 18 at most. So if thats the case 18 x 3 brokers.

Comment: So... lsof | grep flink | wc -l >>>>> 840, of which lsof | grep Kafka | wc -l >>>> 32. The hard limit by default on ubuntu is in the millions, the soft was 1024. So I increased the soft to 65000.